# convert comma-separated string-pairs with regex

Tags: regex

I have a comma-separated list of first- and lastnames which I need to convert to SQL 
(whitespace exists after the comma):

```
joe, cool

alice, parker
```

etc.

should become:

```
( firstname ='joe' and lastname = 'cool' ) or

( firstname ='alice' and lastname = 'parker' )
```

How can I achieve this with a regular expression?

Comment: I'd do it manually in any editor that runs on linux: vi, kate, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl you can do this:

```
s/(\S+),\s*(\S+)/( firstname ='\1' and lastname = '\2' )/
```

From the command line:

```
> perl -pe "s/(\S+),\s*(\S+)/( firstname ='\1' and lastname = '\2' )/" input.txt
```

Input:

```
joe, cool
alice, parker
```

Output:

```
( firstname ='joe' and lastname = 'cool' )
( firstname ='alice' and lastname = 'parker' )
```

Comment: Having a dash in a name (parker-jones) yields this: parker-( lastname ='jones' and firstname = 'sally' )

Comment: I edited.  Replaced `\w` (word character) with `\S` (non-space character).